# Setting global variable value in Perl

Tags: perl

I am having one perl module which sets values of some global variable to constant.
I need to set the value of these global variables to a value which is available to me only when I call the new() .

Is there any way I can achieve it ?

Answer (score 3):

You use `our` to declare a variable as global.  You can then access it from other places in the same package if they also declare it as an `our` variable in their lexical scope.  From outside the package, you can only access it as with a package:: prefix.

Example:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    our $bar = $_[1];
    return bless {}, $_[0];
}

sub get_bar {
    our $bar;
    return $bar;
}
1;
```

In another file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Foo;
my $foo = Foo->new('baz');
print "This is baz: ", $foo->get_bar, "\n";
print "So is this: ", $Foo::bar, "\n";
```